# How to call an R code from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, r

I have an R script say rtry.r which contains 3 statements:

```
c<-3+5
d<-5+11
e<-6+4
```

Also, I have a simple html page which has a "div" element.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Div</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
  <style>
  #box { height: 200px; width: 450px; position: relative; resize:both; overflow:auto; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="box" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Box</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to display the values of "c", "d" and "e" in this box. Is there any way we can run the r script from the javascript?
Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way for now is to run your script on server-side and pass result with an AJAX or at page load. For JavaScript and node.js you could use https://gitorious.org/r-node

Comment: How exactly do I use it in my case?

Answer (score 0):

One way to create web applications with R is to use [Shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/)